# Django linking pages that display elements from a model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to create webpages that link to each other with Django.  I created a model with several elements: title, summary, description01, description02.  On the first page, the home page, I display the title and summary, this seems to work fine.  However, I want a link after the title and summary that links to a page with description01 and then a link to a page with description02.  This is where I am having issues.  I created a file for description01.html, I created a function for it in views.py, a path in urls.py, and added a link to home.  When I try to open the home page, I get error: NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'description01' with arguments '(3,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['articles/$']
Code and Screenshots:
home.html

```
<h1>home</h1>

{% for outline in outline %}

{{ outline.title }}<br>
{{ outline.summary }}<br>
<a href="{% url 'description01' outline.id %}">LInk</a>

{% endfor %}
```

viwes.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Outline
    
def home(request):
    outline = Outline.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'articles/home.html', {'outline': outline})

def description01(request):
    outline = Outline.description01
    return render(request, 'articles/description01.html', {'outline': outline})
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from articles import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('articles/', views.description01, name='description01'),
]
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Outline(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=250, default="")
    description01 = models.CharField(max_length=250, default="")
    description02 = models.CharField(max_length=250, default="")
```

description01.html

```
<h1>description01</h1>

{% for outline in outline %}

{{ outline.description01 }}<br>

{% endfor %}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4GXT.png)

Answer (score 0):

`{% for outline in outline %}` may give you an error, because you could be calling the inner outline or the global one. Try changing it to:

```
{% for otlne in outline %}
    {{ otlne.description01 }}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

Also, there is probably something wrong with `outline = Outline.description01`, don't you mean:

```
def description01(request):
    outline_objs = Outline.objects.all()
    context = {
        'd_01': [outline.description01 for outline in outline_objs]
    }
    return render(request, 'articles/description01.html', context=context)
```

and then:

```
{% for d in d_01 %}
    {{ d }}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

This way, the `d_01` key that would be accessed in the HTML files would be only a list of the `description01` in all Outlines objects.

Comment: You should also avoid using the `01` and `02` names, try something as `first_description'`and `second_description`, or change them to a ListField in the database (not all databases support it).

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have a few questions.  can you explain what is going on when changing: {% for outline in outline %} to {% for otlne in outline %}.  Is "otlne" just an abbreviation for outline? Where do I implement this, in description01.html, home.html, or both?

Comment: Yes, `otline` is just an abbreviation! The idea is that you dont repeat the 'variable' names, so the code is easier to read later on. Even if it's just you that manages it, let's say you get stuck in something and don't read that code for 1 week, its much easier to read if the names don't conflict. As such, I would implement it everywhere.